# What is the difference between System API and Process Api

Tags: api, mule

Kindly, can anyone *differentiate* between **System api** and **Process api**?
Please provide answer in **Generic** terms, as i am unable to find on internet.

Comment: See https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/api-dev/what-is-api-led-connectivity/

Answer (score 7):

A system api abstracts from an existing system. It talks to the system in the language of the system (e.g. SOAP, direct Java calls, SAP calls, etc.). To the outside world it offers a clean API (usually REST with http and json). When you do a good job implementing your system api, you can exchange your existing system with a different/new one without changing the api of your system api to the outside world: Just implement a new system api with different adapter logic.

A process api should talk REST on "both ends". It calls one or several system apis to do its job. The process api orchestrates different jobs.

When you need more information, do a search with "api led connectivity"

Answer (score 5):

A System API is a layer you build on top of a system, which handles all system specific connection quirks and settings. It then exposes these resources and it's logic in a standard format (usualy REST but you're free to choose something else like SOAP) to the rest of your API's. Like Roger Butenuth states:

> "When you do a good job implementing your system api, you can exchange
>   your existing system with a different/new one without changing the api
>   of your system api to the outside world: Just implement a new system
>   api with different adapter logic."

A process API is where you keep your logic and orchestration, it does not 'talk' to end systems directly but instead connects to system API's to get it's data.
A process API should idealy only talk REST on both sides and can aggegrate data from multiple systems.

An example of a complex process API would be an "items you've ordered" API which takes in a user id as it's input, then talks to the system API of a CRM system to get the id used by the "order history system API".
However this API might only return a list of orders without any article information besides an article id. So our Process API then enriches this list with Article information fetched from "article information system API" with the id from the list.

I know it's out of the scope of the question, but for the sake of completeness i'l shortly explain the third variant as well:

An Experience API can be seen as a doorway into your API network, every (type of) client has different information needs and can communicate in different protocols.
It is the Experience API's responsibility to provide ALL the information required by a client in a format they support. 
This takes the responsibility away from a client to know where the information needs to be fetched from. 
(Customer info from CRM, Order info from proprietary sys one, Article info from article DB)
This concept of design has as a bonus that if when for example, the mobile app your company is making, gets some new functionality which requires extra data.
You can update the "mobille app experience api", which would leave your "superexpensive IBM Experience api" unchanged. Cutting down on development costs as you don't need to implement any changes in your other api consumers which would be the case had you had only one api.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main difference is where you are implementing business process and rules/logics.

System API, within the scope of your design, are atomic APIs which will be used to construct higher level API (experience APIs).  Process API is the orchestration layer where you can use Mulesoft flows to implement business process or logic.

Answer (score 2):

System APIs do the heavy lifting work of CRUD operations.
Process APIs focus on business logic

Answer (score 2):

System API's are underlying all IT designs are center frameworks of records that are regularly not promptly accessible because of its many-sided quality and network concerns. APIs give a method for concealing that many-sided quality from the client while uncovering information and giving downstream protection from any interface changes or legitimization of those frameworks.

Process APIs exemplify the fundamental business forms that cooperate with source and target frameworks or channels through an arrangement of framework APIs. For instance, in a buy arrange process, there is some rationale that is regular crosswise over items, geologies and retail channels that can and ought to be refined into a solitary administration that would then be able to be called.

And you will get some more clarity from this article https://dzone.com/articles/api-the-backbone-of-the-software-industry-know-how

Answer (score 1):

System API and Process API will be part of API led connectivity.

System API is like awrapper service to either a main data base or saas platform

Process API involves application logic to validate search or query parameters